# How to fix checkmarx stored XSS issue from datatable gridData binding

Tags: asp.net, xss, checkmarx, secure-coding

Below is the code for retrieving datatable from database

```
protected DataTable ExecuteDataTableSQL(string strSQL)
{
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(_strConnectionString))
    {
        dbAdapter.SelectCommand.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();
        DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            OracleCommand comm = dbAdapter.SelectCommand;
            comm.CommandText = strSQL;
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            dbAdapter.Fill(dtResult);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex);
        }
        return dtResult;
    }
}
```

Below is the simplified code I am using the above method

```
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
string strSQL="some select statement";
dtResult = ExecuteDataTableSQL(strSQL);

if (dtResult.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
    dg.DataSource = dtResult;
    dg.DataBind();
}
```

Checkmarx reports this as stored XSS as gets data from the database, for the dtResult element. This element’s value then flows through the code without being properly filtered or encoded and is eventually displayed to the user in method
source: `dbAdapter.Fill(dtResult);`
destination: `dg.DataSource = dtResult;`

How to resolve the issue.

Comment: other than XSS does Checkmarx report this snippets you shared as SQL Injection? Looked like a primary candidate for me. On the XSS finding, is the Fill method where the flow ends as its sink? Not in a aspx or cshtml page?

Comment: Do you mean the destination as its sink? The destination is an aspx.cs file. If it is an aspx file I could add htmlencode=true to the boundfield or may be it is true by default.